# Plotting A Large Wide Format Data.Frame That Contains NAs

Tags: r, plot

I have a large data.frame that has 2156 observations and 3 variables in long form. The observations include yearly mean measurements for 870 locations (Station.ID) over 39 years. Station.ID can be numeric, character, or both, and not all Station.ID have a measurement for every year. Some measurements are negative numbers. When I imported this data, I also used lubridate to convert the time format to %m/%d/%Y %H:%M and create a column for Year only to get the data.frame Year column. I used the plyr package to summarise and find the mean for each year to create the column Mean in the data.frame.

An example of what the data.frame looks like:

```
Station.ID     Year      Mean
1             1979       0.009
1             1982       0.012
2             2016      -0.0001
A             1999       0.0420
```

I needed the data.frame in wide format, so I used dcast from the splitstackshape package.

```
mydf2<-dcast(mydf,Station.ID~Year,fun=Mean)

View(mydf2)
Station.ID   1979 ... 1982 ... 1999 ... 2016
1           0.009     0.012     NA      NA
2           NA        NA        NA     -0.0001
A           NA        NA        0.0420  NA
```

I also converted to wide format using:

```
mydf3<-dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, c("Station.ID", "Year")), Station.ID~Year, value.var= "mean")
```

They both worked, but the former code produced NaNs where NAs were.

I need to plot this wide format data.frame so the x-axis=Year and the y-axis=Mean, but I keep getting warning messages that NAs introduced by coercion, figure margins too large, and more which I can list if it's helpful. I don't want to remove rows or columns with NAs.

Is there a way to plot this in R?

Comment: It's unclear why the long format isn't suitable for plotting; the way you described sounds like the original (long format) data would work fine. What do you mean when you say you need the data to be in wide format?

Comment: @Cory I have similar issues when I try to plot the long format. I've been instructed to use the wide format, so I am hoping I can look at this data.frame as a plot as well.

Comment: @Cory Sorry, I forgot long format plot does work. I just succeeded plotting the long format, but I'm still hoping I can plot the wide format since I've been asked to use it.